# Understand sed usage

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I use sed to automaticaly update the version in my doxyfile using this :

```
sed -i -e "s/PROJECT_NUMBER.([ ]{2,}=.*)/PROJECT_NUMBER  = $$VERSION/g" ".doxygen"
```

with `$$VERSION = 1.1.0` (for example)

and as a source :

```
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1.0.10
```

But it generate an copy version of my `.doxygen` named `.doxygen-e` and don't change the line. I've tested my regex [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=PROJECT_NUMBER%28%5B%20%5D%7B2,%7D.=.%2a%29&input=PROJECT_NUMBER%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20=%201.0.10).

I don't understand what's wrong given the fact that it works with my plist file using this :

```
sed -i -e "s/@VERSION@/$$VERSION/g" "./$${TARGET}.app/Contents/Info.plist"
```

Comment: Are you attempting this from within a `Makefile`?

Comment: @devnull This is my goal, but I can't even do that in bash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

You need to refer to a shell variable `$FOO` as `$$FOO` in a `Makefile`.  If you are attempting to do it in `bash` or any other shell, saying:

```
$$FOO
```

would result in the numeric PID of the current process concatenated with `FOO`, e.g. if the PID of the current process is `1234`, then you'd get:

```
1234FOO
```

---

That said, your regex seems to be wrong on more than one count.  You say:

```
PROJECT_NUMBER.([ ]{2,}=.*)
```

Since you are **not** using any option for `sed` that would enable the use of Extended Regular Expressions, this would match the string `PROJECT_NUMBER`, followed by one character, followed by `(`, followed by 2 or more whitespaces, an `=` sign, until it encounters the **last** `)` in the string.

Since you haven't mentioned anything about how the line in the file looks like, I'd assume that it's of the form:

```
PROJECT_NUMBER = 42.42
```

The following might work for you:

```
sed 's/\(PROJECT_NUMBER[ ]*=[ ]*\)[^ ]*/\1$VERSION/' filename
```

If invoking from within a Makefile, you'd need to double the `$`.

Comment: Kind of awesome. But, as you mention, I forget to inform you about the source, I've edited the question

Comment: @Samoth It turns out that the assumption regarding the source was correct, so chances are that the above should work for you.

Comment: @Samoth Note that you have _drastically_ modified the `sed` expression.